# How to get rid of random, uneditable stretches?

Tags: modeling

**Hello!**

I had just recently began using Blender, in hopes to create models for a game of mine.

As practice, I was following a tutorial for character modelling on youtube, but had come across a strange issue... As I was down below creating the feet, this had somehow occurred:

[image: Random protrusions from chest]

*[Random protrusions from chest ^]*

After realizing this, I didn't make too big of a deal out of it, until I realized I couldn't edit any part of them (faces, edges, vertices, etc.)...

**The protrusions are endless, at no point does the stretching discontinue.**

I tried saving, closing Blender and reopening to see if that would fix the problem, but it had done no such thing! **Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!**

Here's an additional image (I was going to include several more, but I do not have a reputation of 10 or more):
[image]

Comment: please provide a ,blend file to be able to help you

Comment: These are likely caused by a modifier. What modifier do you have in your stack? Is there a *Bevel* one? Please edit your question and provide more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Switch to Edge Select mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> > <kbd>2</kbd>)
2. Select the protruding edge.
3. <kbd>X</kbd> to delete

Then you can re-add the faces in the chest where the protrusion was.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I I thought I had selected in each of the tree modes (Vertice, Edge, Face).. But it seems I had not. Thank you.

Comment: I've been looking into re-adding the faces, but have found no solution. I selected the edges of the perimeter and hit 'F', which fills the area, but without including the additional edges/vertices that were deleted. I'm sure it's a simple process.. I  just can't seem to find it.

Comment: You are probably getting an ngon. Use vertex select mode, and select the bottom four verts, add face, then repeat for top